# How to use Tivoli Identity Manager in Java?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

I want to create one method which take some parameter like url, token and then validate by the Tivoli Identity Manager, and then return true and false depending of response of the Tivol Identity Manager.

I am new for this so don't know any thing about this so please explain from start.

Comment: Are you talking authentication? If so, is there a reason you're not using TAM/ISAM?